# Java is the front end technology and php is the back end technology. how could I connect both?

Tags: java, php, backend

My company is suppose to create an android application along with it's website. I will be handling the website part. So I need to use php as both app's and site's back end. For site i know to do with php. But for app, how could i connect java and php?

Comment: Why do you need to "connect to PHP" from the app? You just need to connect to the same database, use Java or whichever for the app, and PHP for the website. Basically creating the same thing twice - once in the app, once for web.

Comment: As @qirel mentioned no need to connect php with java just create API under PHP and than use it under JAVA that way bothe the technology will be used.

Comment: How would you even connect to PHP with Java. They're programming languages. You could create an API in PHP which Java uses, but you don't connect to PHP itself.. ;-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you will be building the backend part of the solution you need to build a solution to serve the mobile app also.

As mentioned by @Chirad you want to build a general purpose "REST" API with PHP that will serve the data needs of both the website and mobile app.

So the architecture will be like:

- Website --- get data---> REST API
- Mobile App --- get data ---> REST API
- REST API --- get data ---> data bases

The REST API will connect to databases. Website or mobile app should not have direct database access.

Both end user applications (website and mobile app) will call the same REST API to get the data they need for display purposes.

Googling with "rest api with php" should get you started.